# ReferenceError: addEvent is not defined

Tags: javascript, css

I am a new learner of Javascript and I cannot detect the javascript error.Where is the main problem.  Please help in this case.I am getting error in inspect elements. ReferenceError: addEvent is not defined

http://jsfiddle.net/v7p1bc5u/

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="jsscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Window Open and Close</h1>
    <form action="">
        <p>
            <input type="button" id="create-window" value="Create New Window">
            <input type="button" id="close-window" value="Close New Window">
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>



addEvent(window,'load',initialize);

    function initialize(){
        if(document.getElementById)
        {
            var oButtonCreate = document.getElementById("create-window");
            var oButtonClose = document.getElementById("close-window");
            if (oButtonCreate && oButtonClose)
            {
                oButtonCreate.onclick = makeNewWindow;
                obuttonClose.onclick =closeNewWindow;
            }
        }
    }

    var newWindow;

    function makeNewWindow()
    {
        newWindow = window.open("","","height=300, width=300")  
    }
    function closeNewWindow()
    {
        if(newWindow)
        {
            newWindow.close();
            newWindow =null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Assuming the script in the post is within `jsscript.js`, have you included a library containing `addEvent` method / how have you defined `addEvent`? It is not a native JS or DOM method.

Comment: `addEvent(window,'load',initialize);`  What's `addEvent()`?  `window.addEvent()` isn't a built-in function.

Comment: simple typo: change "addEvent" to "addEventListener.call" ;)

Comment: @dandavis: I wouldn't call that a "typo".  I doubt he meant to write `addEventListener.call`.

Comment: @Teemu: i think `addEventListener.call` would work fine, though using just `addEventListener` and taking out the window would be cleaner. or, better, finding one of the umpteen million "addEvent" scripts from 5 years ago this code seems to expect...

Comment: dandavis & Teemu Thanks addEventListener.call is working now . I was following an old book.

Comment: @dandavis I'd recall to have been learning `addEvent`using FF1.5 or someting like that, it really was years ago.

Comment: yeah, memories... i think addEvent(), getAjax(), and cssQuery() were the cornerstone of any good homebrew "stdlib" before jQuery took off...

Answer (score 0):

Reading the same book, had the same problem.
The thing is they predefine function, and describe it earlier int he book. 
However other users advice using addEventListener directly, which seems to be better practice

```
function addEvent(to, type, fn){
    if(document.addEventListener){
        to.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
    } else if(document.attachEvent){
        to.attachEvent('on'+type, fn);
    } else {
        to['on'+type] = fn;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made use of the that structure below and it worked. Thanks to @IvanN who gave the idea addEventListener

```js
function initialize(){
    if(document.getElementById){
        var oButtonRewrite = document.getElementById('rewritePage');
        
        //if it exists...
        if(oButtonRewrite){
            oButtonRewrite.addEventListener('click',reWrite);
        }
    }
}
window.addEventListener('load',initialize);
```